# AllowUserPasswordChange not working in jasperserver 6.0.1

Tags: jasperserver

I have changed the jasperserver-servlet.xml file in jasperserver 6.0.1 to enable the user password change link on the login screen as below.

From:

```
<property name="allowUserPasswordChange" value="false" />
```

To:

```
<property name="allowUserPasswordChange" value="true" />
```

This enabled the change password link on the login screen but when i am clicking on the link nothing is happening. Do i am missed some settings.